# How to reference the column value in same stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I already have some stored procedure, and now I want to make it one stored procedure.

My stored procedure code looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UP_SELECT_TargetSiteStatus_For_ExcelExport]
    @AppUrl nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Web Application
    SELECT 
        AppName, AppUrl, AppPort,
        AppDefaultTimeZone, AppMaxiumFileSize,
        AppContentDatabaseCount, AppSitesCount
    FROM
        tb_SPStatusWebApplications
    WHERE
        AppUrl = @AppUrl    

    -- Content Database
    SELECT 
        ContentDBAppName, ContentDBID, ContentDBName,
        ContentDBServerName, ContentDBStatus, 
        ContentDBSize, ContentDBSiteCount
    FROM
        tb_SPStatusContentDatabases CD
    INNER JOIN 
        tb_SPStatusWebApplications WA ON CD.ContentDBAppName = WA.AppName
    WHERE
        CD.ContentDBAppName = ?   <-- Change this...
END
```

In first `Select` query, `AppName` value is like this "Site1".

And I want to use `AppName` value to compare with `ContentDBAppname` in second `SELECT` query where clause

```
WHERE
    CD.ContentDBAppName = [how to get AppNames value]
```

But I`m not sure how can I make it...

Please somebody help me

Comment: what will be the input parameter to your new SP ? only `@AppUrl` ? Actually your 2nd SP will be able to return all required columns including those in SP1

Comment: yeah new SP parameter value is only @AppUrl, and AppName value and ContentDBAppName value is same part. So I try to find how to refer AppName value and compare with ContentDBAppName value

Comment: You can achieve that easily but you can't have two unconditional select statement in the same stored procedure, it will always return value with the last select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TRY THIS**: your second select statement will be as below and you are already joining AppName in the join so you can add in **AND** condition as
**AND WA.AppUrl = @AppUrl** or in where.

```
SELECT 
        ContentDBAppName
    ,   ContentDBID
    ,   ContentDBName
    ,   ContentDBServerName
    ,   ContentDBStatus
    ,   ContentDBSize
    ,   ContentDBSiteCount
FROM tb_SPStatusContentDatabases CD
INNER JOIN tb_SPStatusWebApplications WA ON CD.ContentDBAppName = WA.AppName
    AND WA.AppUrl = @AppUrl
```

It will return AppName exactly same as first select statement and will perform same in the join as per your expectation.

Comment: Oh thank you Suraz, I made a sp from your advice, and it wokrs perfectly! and also appreciate for your detailed explanation :)